# If $A, B$ are finite sets, show that $|B^A| = |B|^{|A|}$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

The set of all functions from $A$ to $B$ is $B^A.$ Then the cardinality of $B^A$ is denoted $|B^A|$.

Let $f: A \to B$. Then we can write $f = \{(1,b), (2,b), (3, b) \ldots, (a, b) \}.$ Thus, there are $a$ ways to pick $b$s. So, there are $b^a$ functions from $A$ to $B$.

If we let $|A| = a$ and $|B| = b,$ then there $|B|^{|A|}$ functions from $A$ to $B$.

Then, $|B^A| = |B|^{|A|}$.

Would you agree?

edit: Let $f = \{(1,?), (2,?), (3, ?) \ldots, (a, ?) \}.$ In how many ways can we replace $?$s in $f$?

Comment: Exactly; this works

Comment: You know what's going on. However, the argument is not well-expressed, and one cannot expect it to be understood.  For example, $f=\{(1,b),\dots, (a,b)\}$ is not right.

Comment: @ André Nicolas, I could probably clean it up by saying the left side of the equality is just a cardinality notation while the right side is by counting the number of functions between $A$ and $B$. In the set of pairs instead of $b$, I could just use the symbol $'?'$.

Comment: You have used $a$ and $b$ before saying what they are. At one time they look like variables that range over $A$ and $B$ respectively, but later they seem to be the cardinalities of these two sets. You have assumed that $A=\{1,2,\dots,a\}$, and similarly for $B$, which from the point of view of counting is OK, but is a bit of a jump. If you want to make that assumption, you should then say that in building a function $f$, there are $b$ choices for $f(1)$. For every  one of these choices, there are $b$ choices for $f(2)$, $\dots$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your proof is correct. ${}{}$